# enum to be stored in DB

Tags: java, android, database, enums

I have a enum class like this -

```
public enum FeedbackStatus {
    @JsonProperty("unprocessed")
    UNPROCESSED("unprocessed"),

    @JsonProperty("arrived")
    ARRIVED("arrived"),

    @JsonProperty("performed")
    PERFORMED("performed"),

    @JsonProperty("cancelled")
    CANCELLED("cancelled"),

    @JsonProperty("removed")
    REMOVED("removed"),

    @JsonProperty("no-show")
    NO_SHOW("no-show"),

    @JsonProperty("cancel-at-door")
    CANCEL_AT_DOOR("cancel-at-door");

    private static final FeedbackStatus[] myEnumValues = FeedbackStatus.values();
    private final String fieldDescription;

    private FeedbackStatus(String value) {
        this.fieldDescription = value;
    }

    public static FeedbackStatus fromString(String string) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
            for (FeedbackStatus feedbackStatus : myEnumValues) {
                if (feedbackStatus.getString().equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
                    return feedbackStatus;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No constant with text " + string + " found");
    }

    public String getString() {
        return this.fieldDescription;
    }
}
```

I need to store an object `feedback` in SQLITE database using GreneDAO but the object is a enum and hence I am unable to store it  . The object is like -

```
private FeedbackStatus feedback;
```

How can  I store it as String?

Answer (score 0):

Use for ex. CANCELLED.value? When storing the data? There is also ENUM.toString(). You can store it as String and then wrap recovering data with String to Enum method.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store `enums` in database as `enumns` are `Java` entity, so for enums you need to store their equivalent values either `String` or `int` etc.

You can get `value` of `enum` as below and than store it in `database` as `Strings`:

```
String PERFORMED = PERFORMED.value; 
String CANCELLED= CANCELLED.value; 
String REMOVED= REMOVED.value; 
String NO_SHOW= NO_SHOW.value; 
String CANCEL_AT_DOOR= CANCEL_AT_DOOR.value;
```

For more details of Enums see [Java Docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)

So here actually your data model is ok but while saving enum in the database you just need one column with enum value, and while inserting you need to convert from enum to its string value and while reading from db, you need to build enum from that string.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: How do I do it in my example

Comment: This is for getting values. For storing values, should i store it separately as for each string PERFORMED,CANCELLED..?

Comment: Yes but for storing values?

Comment: i could not understand what are you saying. please can you elaborate

Comment: I mean when I store these 5 strings, there will be 5 separate columns for each string? And why should I do PERFORMED.value?

Comment: even you save all with different columns, to get value of enums you need to call that enumInstance.value to get it's value

Comment: btw you can not store enum so there won;t be 5 columns, but you need to store String value of all enum into database, for example for boolean there are no 2 columns for true and false, there is only one column for boolean and you store 1 or 0 in that column, and you do marshalling and unmarshalling

Comment: Ok so saving 5 strings in each different column is of no problem?

Comment: I am sorry I really dont get it

Comment: Or should I sace a single string say FEEDBACK and then read the value from it?

Comment: actually your data model is ok but while saving enum in the database you just need one column with enum value, and while inserting you need to convert from enum to it's string value and while reading from db, you need to build enum from that string.

Comment: Ok... So finally can I save this as a single String and then read the value of it and pass it to enum?

Comment: @shriduttkothari Why would you reinvent the wheel when serialization already does all this for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can just [serialize/deserialize it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#enum). [Enums are serializable by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).